# Python Beautiful Soup - output .string results separately

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am creating a discord bot that scrapes book titles from a website and I am looking to differentiate the different results I am getting.

```
name = "Raymond"
r = requests.get("https://websitehere/s/{}?order=bestmatch".format(name), headers=headers, verify=False)
results = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(results, "lxml")
for a in soup.find_all("a",style="text-decoration: underline;", limit=5):
```

With this code I am retrieving the first 5 titles of the search result.
Since it is for a discord bot I need to output them one by one to put them in the following expression:

```
message = f"{a.string[1]}\n\n"
message += f"{a.string[2]}\n"
message += f"{a.string[3]}\n"
message += f"{a.string[4]}\n"
message += f"{a.string[5]}\n"
```

if I use a.string it will give me the 5 results at the same time and a.string[1] outputs only 1 letter (which isn't even the first letter of the title...)

Which argument could I use?

EDIT: minimal code --

```
import requests, urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

name = "Raymond"
r = requests.get("https://1lib.ch/s/{}?order=bestmatch".format(name), verify=False)
results = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(results, "lxml")
for a in soup.find_all("a",style="text-decoration: underline;", limit=2):
    print(a.string)
```

Output:

```
Raymond Carver
Technique and sensibility in the fiction and poetry of Raymond Carver
```

What I'd like to do is to have a result as follows and this automatically.

```
message = f"{"Raymond Carver"}\n\n"
message += f"{"Technique and sensibility in the fiction and poetry of Raymond Carver"}\n"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "a.string it will give me the 5 results at the same time" -- with the code you posted so far, I doubt this is the case as `a` from `for a in soup.find_all("a",style="text-decoration: underline;", limit=5):` is just one tag and not all five tags. Post a [mre].

Comment: @JustinEzequiel thank you for the feedback. You're right it doesn't give me all the results at the same time but as a list. I added the min example you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Gather the tag contents first as a list then join them together later.

```py
a_strings = [a.string for a in for a in soup.find_all("a",style="text-decoration: underline;", limit=5)]

message = '\n'.join(a_strings)
```

If you want an extra linebreak after the first line, then you can insert an empty string at index 1 before you do the join.

```py
a_strings.insert(1, '')
```